# Android: name of current (system) theme

Tags: android, themes

How would I get current system theme `name` or `ID` using `getTheme()` function?

I would like to set the `theme` of my application to `DARK` if the current theme would be `LIGHT`. This is because `MIUI` has (I think) the `LIGHT` theme and some things aren't visible in my app (see "Set timer" string:

[image]

Comment: Why not just always set your app theme to DARK? (even if the system theme is DARK)